# Передача аргумента в функцию по значению или по ссылке?

Tags: c++

Изучая С++ заметил, что авторы статей/книг не рекомендуют передавать значения примитивных типов по ссылке. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше поступать и почему?

Мои догадки, почему лучше использовать передачу по значению: на создание параметра-ссылки уходит в 2 раза больше памяти, бывает необходимо менять значение параметра без влияния на переменную-аргумент caller'а.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему примитивы нужно передавать по значению?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510534/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: А еще лучше, вообще забудьте о ссылках. Если что-то может меняться в функции -- передавайте указатель. Меньше будет проблем с  пониманием кода при его чтении

Answer (score 4):

Можно работать и так, и так. Работа со ссылкой означает, что где-то там за сценой получается адрес очередного элемента, и при работе с этим элементом выполняется разыменование. По значению - что выполняется копирование.

А потому надо смотреть, что именно вам нужно - например, если вы хотите изменять элементы в массиве, то нужно работать по ссылке. Если, наоборот, вы хотите изменять содержимое переданного аргумента, но при этом хотите, чтобы это не отразилось на исходной переменной - работайте по значению. Если ситуация допускает и тот, и иной вариант - стоит посмотреть, какая операция - разыменования (возможно, не одна) или копирования - обойдется дороже. Для простых типов небольшого размера копирование, как правило, дешевле. Но вообще говоря - тут надо даже не смотреть на конкретный код, а профилировать его - если, конечно, оно того стоит с точки зрения оптимизации.

И не забывайте, что можно использовать еще и константную ссылку :) Потому что передача по ссылке автоматически требует наличия lvalue, так что функцию `f(int&);` вы как `f(5);` не вызовите...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*